# How does quicksort handle case when we choose the first number as pivot and all the remaining elements after the pivot is greater

Tags: algorithms, quicksort

For example, we have an array [4,7,6,13] and I choose the first item 4 as the pivot. Now I have a pointer **i** that goes through the array from index 1 to index 3; and I have another pointer **j** that starts at index 1, increases whenever we find an element that is smaller than pivot and we swap this element with the element j is now pointing to. Now since all elements are greater than 4, when my **i** reaches the end of the array, **j** is still at index 1. Now I have to switch 4 and 7, which doesn't make sense. However, according to the algorithm, we need to swap them. Did I miss anything here?

Comment: Make $j$ point to the pivot element. And increase it only when you find an element which is smaller than pivot.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. Please provide a reference for *(Lomuto?) partition* / *quicksort*: why would one `have to switch 4 and 7`?